# SQL join multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a user status list of the following format ***"A like B's XXX"***. A and B are both registered users and have firstname and lastname and user id. How to join the status table with the user table twice to get the names of the two users? Thank you.

```
SELECT "SQACTION"."TIMECREATED", 
       "SQWORDLIST".*, 
       "SUBJECT"."FIRSTNAME" subject_fn,
       "SUBJECT"."LASTNAME" subject_ln, 
        author.firstname author_fn, 
        author.lastname author_ln 
FROM "SQACTION" 
  INNER JOIN "SQWORDLIST"
    ON SQACTION.ACTION = SQWORDLIST.GUID 
  INNER JOIN "SQUSER" SUBJECT
    ON SQACTION.SUBJECT = SUBJECT.GUID 
  LEFT JOIN SQDOCUMENT
    ON SQACTION.ENTITY = SQDOCUMENT.GUID 
  LEFT JOIN SQUSER AUTHOR
    ON SQDOCUMENT.AUTHORID = AUTHOR.GUID 
WHERE (SUBJECT.GUID = 'B4D3BF632C0C4DB3AB01C8B284069D8F') 
   OR (SUBJECT.GUID IN ('67882AF3FA3C4254AF9A12CA0B0AB6E4',
                        '6A4B52FE233444838AACFE2AFFE4D38F',
                        '8CA3FB9061FF4710B51F1E398D3D1917')) 
ORDER BY "TIMECREATED" DESC
```

This is what I have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean something like, status have two field links to user table?

```
select user_a.first_name as user_a_first_name, user_b.first_name as user_b_first_name, status.status_name
from status
left join users as user_a on user_a.id = status.user_from_id 
left join users as user_b on user_b.id = status.user_to_id
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make a subject-verb-object format status. The subject is a user, and the object can be either a user itself or a user's stuff.

Comment: I store user's name and user's stuff on two separate tables. The id is global.

Comment: what's the relationship between status and user a and user?

Comment: User A is the creator of the relationship and user B is the receiver of user A's action. A status looks like "Bob likes Anna's Blog" or "Bob waves to Anna".

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the table name twice in the `FROM` clause, and use an alias so you can specify which fields from each instance of the table are used in the `ON` statement.  You didn't provide enough details in your question to give an exact example, so here is something more general.

UserTable, with ID & Name

RegTable, with UserID, and SponsorID

```
select ut1.name as [User],
       ut2.name as [Sponsor]
from   UserTable ut1
       inner join RegTable rt on ut1.id = rt.userid
       inner join UserTable ut2 on rt.sponsorid = ut2.id
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I have three tables. One is for status, one is for users and the other is for user created documents (blogs, photos, etc) The status table store user's id only and I am trying to join the user table to get user's first name and last name.